# How to show last row of Pandas DataFrame in box plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, boxplot

**Random data**:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(20,4)))
    data

                0           1           2          3
    0   -0.710006   -0.748083   -1.261515    0.048941
    1    0.856541    0.533073    0.649113   -0.236297
    2   -0.091005   -0.244658   -2.194779    0.632878
    3   -0.059058    0.807661   -0.418446   -0.295255
    4   -0.103701    0.775622    0.258412    0.024411
    5   -0.447976   -0.034419   -1.521598   -0.903301
    6    1.451105    0.549661   -1.655751   -0.147499
    7    1.479374   -1.475347    0.665726    0.236611
    8   -1.427979   -1.812916    0.522802    0.006066
    9    0.198515    1.203476   -0.475389   -1.721707
    10   0.286255    0.564450    0.590050   -0.657811
    11  -1.076161    1.820218   -0.315127   -0.848114
    12   0.061848    0.303502    0.978169    0.024630
    13  -0.307827   -1.047835    0.547052   -0.647217
    14   0.679214    0.734134    0.158803   -0.334951
    15   0.469675    1.043391   -1.449727    1.335354
    16  -0.483831   -0.988185    0.264027   -0.831833
    17  -2.013968   -0.200699    1.076526    1.275300
    18  -0.199473   -1.630597   -1.697146   -0.177458
    19   1.245289    0.132349    1.054312   -0.082550

    data.boxplot(vert= False, figsize = (15,10))
```

[image]

**I want to add red dots to the box plot indicating the last value (bottom) in each column.** For example (red dots I've edited in are not in their exact position, but this gives you a general idea):

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add a scatter plot on top of the boxplot.
For the provided example, it looks like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
df.boxplot(vert= False, patch_artist=True, ax=ax, zorder=1)
lastrow = df.iloc[-1,:]
print(lastrow)
ax.scatter(x=lastrow, y=[*range(1,len(lastrow)+1)], color='r', zorder=2)

# for displaying the values of the red points:
for i, val in enumerate(lastrow,1):
    ax.annotate(text=f"{val:.2f}", xy=(val,i+0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! This seems to work, but there is one issue: I passed patch_artist = True to the data.boxplot() function call in order to color in the box plot, but this seems to overlap any red dots inside the square so that they are not visible. Is there a way to force the red dots to be on top of the box plots? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use `zorder` to arrange the layers of your plots.

Comment: Brilliant my friend! That did the trick. Another question: from your code, it seems like every horizontal grid line on the y-axis has an integer value associated with it. Hence, your use of y=[*range(1,len(lastrow)+1)] to designate the lines to put the red dots on. With this in mind, is it possible to put the value corresponding to each dot above it? For example, for the bottom red dot, can you put something like 1.25 (or whatever the value is) above it, given that it would be placed above the 0 y-axis line? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: glad I could help. Yes, here we can use [`plt.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html). I'll update the answer.

Comment: My friend, you helped a lot with this question. I don't know how to reach out on here (via direct message) to you directly, so I figured I would try through this comment. I've been struggling with another graph for a couple of days, and I posted a question on here but nobody has answered. Do you mind if I share link here?

Comment: It looks to me you only need to change the ticklabels. I will have a look in the morning and also why your way is not working!

Comment: Yeah, I think it must be something minor I am overlooking. Thank you for your help; take your time!